# No matching function for call c++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typedef

I am getting this error.

> `error: no matching function for call to ‘namespaceA::ClassA<namespaceB::someFunc<short int, 3u>, namespaceB::someFunc<float, 3u> >::funcFromA(int&, void (namespaceB::classB<namespaceB::someFunc<short int, 3u>, namespaceB::someFunc<float, 3u> >::*)(void*), int&)’`
>
> `note: candidates are: void namespaceA::ClassA<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::funcFromA(int, void (namespaceA::ClassA<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::*)(void*), int) [with TYPE_A = namespaceB::someFunc<short int, 3u>, TYPE_B = namespaceB::someFunc<float, 3u>]`

Classes are something like this

ClassA.h

```
template<typename TYPE_A, typename TYPE_B>
class ClassA {

typedef void (ClassA::*someTypeDef)(void*);

void funcFromA(int A, namespaceA::ClassA<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::
                  someTypeDef takeFunc, int B);

}
```

ClassA.cxx

```
void namespaceA::ClassA::funcFromA(int A, 
          namespaceA::ClassA::someTypeDef takeFunc, int B) {
    // Do something with taken function
}
```

ClassB.h

```
template<typename TYPE_A, typename TYPE_B>
class classB {
void classB<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::CallThisFunc(void *someParm);
    // Do Something
}
```

ClassB.cxx

```
template<typename TYPE_A, typename TYPE_B>
void classB<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::CallThisFunc(void *someParm){
    // Do something
}

template<typename TYPE_A, typename TYPE_B>
void classB<TYPE_A, TYPE_B>::MainFunc() {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 1;
    ClassA->funcFromA(A, &classB::CallThisFunc, B); // <--- Error
}
```

I attempted to fix the error, but I was unsuccessful and it is killing me.
How do I fix this problem?

Edit : The basic idea I am trying to accomplish is there are two classes, and I am trying to call ClassA function inside ClassB, and ClassB is templated and one of the parameter in ClassA method from ClassB is typedef.

Comment: This is to convoluted to make sense of, please post more code, seriously, and break that error up a few lines, it's hard to read by scrolling! I'm waiting to answer, so write a comment with @AlecTeal in it please.

Comment: I broke the code into few more lines, and the error message as well. Sorry about that. Does this help?

Comment: can you post an example of exactly what you are trying to compile

Answer (score 0):

The function `ClassA<A, B>::funcFromA()` takes a member function of `ClassA<A, B>` as parameter. You try to pass it a member function of `ClassB<A, B>` as argument, though. Since `ClassA<A, B>` and `ClassB<A, B>` are unrelated, this clearly won't work.

BTW, the redundant qualification of `ClassB<A, B>::CallThisFunc` doesn't make your code more readable and I think it is actually illegal although some compilers accept it.